# Translating a GET with Entity Framework to a GET without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, entity-framework

I am following a tutorial online for ASP.NET MVC & Angular, but the author(Sourav Mondal) uses Entity to query the database. Unfortunately, I am using SQL Server 2000, and EF is not an option. The following is the code which I am attempting to transpose:

```
// GET: /Data/
//For fetch Last Contact
public JsonResult GetLastContact()
{
       Contact c = null;
       //here MyDatabaseEntities our DBContext
       using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
       {
           c = dc.Contacts.OrderByDescending(a => a.ContactID).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
       }
       return new JsonResult { Data = c, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

This is my current speculation for an EF-less solution, supposing the Contacts have three fields in the database,`ContactID`, `Name`, and `Password`:

`Models/Contact.cs` class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

`Controllers/DataController.cs`,`GetLastContact()`:

```
public class DataController : Controller
{
    // GET: /Data/
    public JsonResult GetLastContact()
    {

        Contact c = null;
        using (SqlConnection cnxn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TheConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 ContactID FROM Northwind ORDER BY ContactID DESC "))
            {
                cnxn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = sqlQuery.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string contact_ID = (string)reader["ContactID"];
                    string first_name = (string)reader["Name"];
                    string password = (string)reader["Password"];
                }
                // Some magic here

                reader.Close();
                cnxn.Close();
            }
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = c, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

And Sourav's Angular code:

```
        angular.module('MyApp') //extending from previously created angular module in the previous part
        .controller('Part2Controller', function ($scope, ContactService) { //inject ContactService
            $scope.Contact = null;
            ContactService.GetLastContact().then(function (d) {
                $scope.Contact = d.data; // Success
            }, function () {
                alert('Failed'); // Failed
            });
        })
        .factory('ContactService', function ($http) { // here I have created a factory which is a populer way to create and configure services
            var fac = {};
            fac.GetLastContact = function () {
                return $http.get('/Data/GetLastContact');
            }
            return fac;
        });
```

I feel like although my solution is probably spaghetti, it cannot be too far off from working. Any little nudge anyone could give this code would be awesome! Or any constructive advice as to how one should proceed in stripping Entity of its Entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Some magic here
c = new Contact
{
  Name = first_name,
  Password = password
};
// end of magic
```

Comment: Of course! I also forgot to declare the strings used for the fields outside of the loop. Thank you!￼

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you want what you want.

For me its sounds more like you want to make your own entity for your database (which does not support EF)

So just make some class of the table and get a List of it so thats it.

Little Example:

SomeClass

List allContactsInDatabase;

To Keep your Data updated use polling or just call a refresh every 30 seconds or faster/slower how you need it.

Hope thats helps